# Change domain name without changing host (OVH)

Tags: seo, domains, wordpress, migration

One of my clients is re-branding, and we need to change the domain name for their site as their business name has changed. They're staying with the same host (OVH), same exact site (only the logo will be changed). No emails.

I've never done this before and want to make sure I'm doing this right. I've contacted OVH to know what they recommend doing, and it just doesn't sound right?

Here's what they said I should do:

- Buy the new domain
- Add it via the client's customer account going to 'Hosting > Multisite' following these steps: https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/hosting/multisites-configuring-multiple-websites/ targeting the 'www' root folder we're currently using
- Go into their Wordpress back-office and change the website's URL there
- Regenerate the SSL certificate

It feels like it's missing a few steps?

- Edit the database in PhpMyAdmin to reflect the change of domain
- Add a 301 redirect via the .htaccess file
- Tell Google about the move

Does that sound right? Even then, what happens to the old domain?

Answer (score 1):

You should also update all internal links you placed in blog posts to new domain. Verify that only HTTPS or HTTP is used and that only the www or non-www version of the site is accessible. The others should redirect to the proper site.

Answer (score 1):

Um, I have experienced about same case as you in wordpress and Wix.
You are now using Wordpress, and do you want to remain google ranking of your site?
Then, you should use duplicator plugin in wordpress, and upload it to new hosting driver.
The way using duplicator plugin is easy.
In my experience, two domains - old domain and new domain use same hosting driver, when, some unexpected issues happened in google rankings.
Rather than, you'd better use separated domain hosting.
Good luck!